# Symfony3 EasyAdmin Custom non-auto ID column

Tags: symfony, doctrine, yaml, symfony2-easyadmin

I have setup a database table in which the ID values will be created by my application and NOT the database.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", precision=14, options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue("NONE")
 */
private $id;
```

This works fine in symfony, but I am trying to edit the table using EasyAdmin and EasyAdmin simply omits the 'id' column.

I found out that I can [manipulate edit/new views configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html) from EasyAdmin documentation.

Now I have the following configuration (the mentioned `id` is for `Product`):

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Category
        - AppBundle\Entity\Product
```

Question:

1- How do I setup the YAML configuration so `id` field will also appear? I found out that this partially works:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Product:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Product
            form:
                fields:
                    - 'id'
```

But this shows only 'id', is there a way to tell that I want 'id' in addition to all the other fields so I don't have to list them manually?

2- My original config is using a list of entities with dash (-) in the YAML file. I am a YAML noob, when I make a `Product:` key I am not able to use the dash anymore, is there a way to keep using dash list and just make an exception for 'Product? For example the code below does NOT work, it says it is not valid YAML.

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Category
        Product:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Product
            form:
                fields:
                    - 'id'
```

Well, for now I solved the problem like this and abandoned the dash notation altogether:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Category:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Category
        Store:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Store
        Product:
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Product
            edit:
                fields:
                    - { property: 'stores', label: 'Stores', type_options: { by_reference: false } }
            form:
                fields:
                    - 'id'
                    - 'name'
                    - 'category'
                    - 'stores'
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: you can use customization based on entity controllers. See doc here: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html#customization-based-on-entity-controllers

```
app/config/config.yml
User:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    controller: UserBundle\Controller\Admin\UserController
```

And then in your UserController you can have something like this. Pay attention you must use the exact entity name in method signature: create**User**EntityFormBuilder in your case

```
protected function createUserEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view)
{
    $form = parent::createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view);

    $form->add('Anyfield', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'id' // feel free to add other options
    ]); // add fieldlike you would do in FormType
    $form->remove('anyField');

    return $form;
}
```

Q2: I can't answer to this question for sure. I do not use "Dashed" notation. 
Maybe take a look at doc here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#collections

Comment: I think the dash notation is much nicer, because I just have to put paths to entities. But for now I solved the problem by only changing config.yml